# How to handel custom error message in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

**What do you have ?**

My frontend is made on Nuxt js and backend is made in node and graphql.

I have the following code snippet from my controller to generate relevant error message:

```js
createUser: async function ({ userInput }, req) {
      const errors = []
      if (!validator.isEmail(userInput.email)) {
        errors.push({ message: 'Email is invalid' })
      }
      //other custom error code
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        error = new Error('Invalid input')
        error.data = errors;
        error.code = 422;
        throw  error
      }
      //other code if no error
}
```

And my frontend code to reach the controller method from the page (register):

```js
methods: {
    async onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      const graphqlQuery = { //query code goes here}
        const res = await this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8080/graphql', graphqlQuery, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.error.mode = true
          this.error.title = 'Success ! '
          this.error.message = 'Account created successfully. Please login'
          this.error.type = 'success'
        }
        if (res.errors && res.errors[0].status === 422) {
          this.error.mode = true
          this.error.title = 'Verification failed ! '
          this.error.message = res.errors[0].message
          this.error.type = 'danger'
        }
        if (res.errors) {
          this.error.mode = true
          this.error.message = 'User creation failed ! '
          this.error.type = 'danger'
        }
      }
    }
```

And custom error page:

```html
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col class="error-wrapper">
        <h1 class="error-code">
          {{ statusCode }}
        </h1>
        <h4>
          {{ message }}
        </h4>
        <b-link to="/" class="btn to-home">
          Home
        </b-link>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ErrorVue',
  layout: 'default',
  props: {
    error: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    statusCode () {
      return (this.error && this.error.statusCode) || 500
    },
    message () {
      return this.error.message || 'Error'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**What are you trying to do ?**

I'm trying to handle and display the custom error code with in the page, with the above error handling code.

**What is the issue ?**

When I intentionally pass wring data to cause error. I'm being redirected to error page with status `500`.

I'm not able to console log error in the page(register) but able to log in the `error.vue` page.
The error does contain the custom code and message. And I want to display them in page from where the method was initiated(register).

How do I display the custom message in `the register.vue` page ? Or does anyone have alternative method to approach the issue ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the first image, the error is 500, which isn't what you're expecting, you should start investigating in the server first. after getting a proper expected error you should handle Axios errors in a catch block.